# GlusterFS fails to mount on boot but mounts later in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, glusterfs

Having two machines, profitmargin and revisionist, I created a volume in profitmargin:

```
root@profitmargin:~# gluster volume info

Volume Name: uploads
Type: Distribute
Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 1
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: profitmargin:/var/lib/gluster/brick01
```

and in revisionist I added this line to fstab to mount it at boot time:

```
profitmargin:/uploads /mnt/uploads glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

but when the computer boots it's not mounted:

```
root@revisionist:~# mount
/dev/mapper/revisionist-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
```

In the log files I found this:

```
root@revisionist:~# cat /var/log/glusterfs/mnt-uploads.log
[2014-05-19 10:41:18.591355] I [glusterfsd.c:1493:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.2.5
[2014-05-19 10:41:18.704144] E [common-utils.c:125:gf_resolve_ip6] 0-resolver: getaddrinfo failed (Name or service not known)
[2014-05-19 10:41:18.704195] E [name.c:253:af_inet_client_get_remote_sockaddr] 0-glusterfs: DNS resolution failed on host profitmargin
[2014-05-19 10:41:18.704236] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:740:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: failed to connect with remote-host: Success
[2014-05-19 10:41:18.704375] W [glusterfsd.c:727:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(glusterfs_mgmt_init+0x1d0) [0x7f1bc152c850] (-->/usr/lib/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_start+0x12) [0x7f1bc0e93c72] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(+0x8abf) [0x7f1bc152cabf]))) 0-: received signum (1), shutting down
[2014-05-19 10:41:18.704400] I [fuse-bridge.c:3727:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/mnt/uploads'.
```

and if I try to mount it later, it works:

```
root@revisionist:~# mount -a
root@revisionist:~# mount
/dev/mapper/revisionist-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
profitmargin:/uploads on /mnt/uploads type fuse.glusterfs (rw,allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072)
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm aware of the bug related to the init script, but I'm running GlusterFS version 3.2.5-1ubuntu1 which has the fix. I am also aware of some IPv6 so I made sure both IPv4 and IPv6 work fine:

```
root@revisionist:~# ping profitmargin
PING profitmargin (192.168.1.111) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from profitmargin (192.168.1.111): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.355 ms
64 bytes from profitmargin (192.168.1.111): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.417 ms
^C
--- profitmargin ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.355/0.386/0.417/0.031 ms
root@revisionist:~# ping6 profitmargin
PING profitmargin(profitmargin) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from profitmargin: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.637 ms
64 bytes from profitmargin: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.472 ms
64 bytes from profitmargin: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.407 ms
64 bytes from profitmargin: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.393 ms
64 bytes from profitmargin: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.402 ms
^C
--- profitmargin ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.393/0.462/0.637/0.092 ms
```

Any other ideas what could be causing this issue and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Struggling with absolutely the same behavior on CentOS7. Tried to point at the mount server using IP address instead of hostname and got `0-glusterfs: DNS resolution failed on host 192.168.1.101` in the log.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but it seems that it is related to the machine revisionlist not resolving profitmargin's ip address through DNS. Maybe the mount command is executed before the network service and that is why revisionlist is no able to locate profitmargin. After bringing up the network service it is able to locate the machine. You should try to find a way to GlusterFS mounts to wait for network service to be online.

Comment: The entries are actually in /etc/hosts, but also, _netdev should cause this entry to not mount until network is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was, that i had enabled --with-ipv6-default when compiling glusterfs. After removing this option the hostname resolution and also explicit ipv4 addresses were use able again.

In your case the log indicates something similar:

```
[2014-05-19 10:41:18.704144] E [common-utils.c:125:gf_resolve_ip6] 0-resolver: getaddrinfo failed (Name or service not known)
```

gf_resolve_ip6 indicates, that glusterfs tried to resolve this as an ipv6 address

Comment: Given that the  question was asked in 2014 and the poster also indicates the specific version of GlusterFS in use it would be great if the answer would indicate in how far it is relevant to a version of GlusterFS from 8 years ago.